# postgres st_dwithin doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-12

Here is my OS & db version

```
cat /etc/centos-release

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)



################################################

psql --version

PostgreSQL 12.1
```

I already installed postgres and postgis.

[image]

but still, I cannot use ST_Dwithin or ST_Distance ... and so on.
I can use stddev... ? (this is useless method to me currently)

[image]
this means -> "No function matches the specified name and argument data types. You may need to add explicit casters"

What more should I check? Please let me know.

Comment: I think you are providing something numeric, it should be geometry eg. ST_DWithin(geometry g1, geometry g2, double precision distance_of_srid).

Comment: yes maybe. but I mean "ST_Dwithin" is not activated in my dbeaver. unlike other method. @BhartiMohane

Comment: Why do you need to activate functions in DBeaver? I think you should just use the function, but with appropriate arguments (see [the documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_DWithin.html)).

Comment: thanks about your comment, but I already know "ST_Dwithin" is not dbeaver function. it's postgis thing. I doubt that the function is not visible even though I am using the postgis extension. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: The function is visible unless you removed the `public` schema from your `search_path`. Use arguments of the appropriate type.

Comment: Can you also add to your question how you're calling the function and what the parameters look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) using numeric parameters instead of *geometries*, and therefore the error message:

> .. Function st_dwithin(numeric, numeric, integer) does not exist ..

This function expects 1) geometry 2) geometry and 3) double precision.

```
SELECT 
  ST_DWithin(
  'POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))'::GEOMETRY,
  'POINT (29 10)'::GEOMETRY,
  3000);
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood using postgis. I didn't have any geometry type column.